# How to use namespace across several files

Tags: c++, namespaces, header-files

I notice that C++'s `std` namespace is spread across several files (like in `vector`, `string`, `iostream`, etc.). How can I accomplish the same thing in my programs? Do I simply declare the same namespace in each individual header file, so that it's something like:

a.h

```
namespace something
{
class A {};
}
```

b.h

```
#include "a.h"

namespace something
{
class B : public A {};
}
```

And then in, say, `main.cpp`, I would just include "b.h" and "a.h" and then `using namespace something;` to use the two classes?

Comment: I assume you mean `using namespace` not `use namespace`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly how to do it.