# Can the definition of a namespace span multiple translation units?

Tags: c++, namespaces, programming-languages

I have seen the definition of a namespace is split across multiple header files, and the header files are included in one file. For example, [How to use namespace across several files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4637811)

Can the definition of a namespace span multiple translation units?

I am comparing namespaces in C++ to packages in Java. A package in Java can span multiple translation units.

Comment: Yes of course. You routinely include various combinations of standard headers into various source files; those headers all contain different pieces of namespace `std`

Comment: Do those header files belong to the same translation unit?

Comment: Of course they do. `<iostream>` defines `std::istream`, `std::ostream`, and others. `<algorithm>` defines `std::find()`, `std::transform()`, and others. Etc...

Comment: By definition, a translation unit is a source file together with all the files included into it; roughly, a single source file after it passed preprocesssor. In light of this, your question doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks. What good book do you recommend for C++? I have The C++ Programming Language, but I like OReilly's in a nutshell more, and C++ in a Nutshell is outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namespace doesn't have declaration and definition. Declarations and definitions are in the namespaces.

Translation unit is everything you get after being preprocessed. In particular, preprocessor includes header files to the source files.

Imagine you have one header and two source files with namespaces. After preprocessing you get namespace from header spans two source files. And it will be compiled.

So you can split namespace between source files.

**header.h**

```
namespace ns {

void f1();
void f2();

}
```

**source1.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"

namespace ns {

void f1() {

}

}
```

**source2.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"

namespace ns {

void f2() {

}

}
```

And stop compare C++ and Java. They have different fundamental concepts.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give some example of splitting the definition of a namespace in different translation units? A translation unit is a .cpp file after expansion of the included header files by the preprocessor.

Comment: Er, a translation unit is everything you get _after_ being preprocessed.

Comment: I mean it. Sorry for my English.

Comment: LOL, no problem. I thought that might be the issue.